# :couldn't find the gcc toolchain

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have now downloaded cocos2dx 3 and when I run build_native.py in cmd I allways get that error:

couldn't find the gcc toolchain

**How can I correct that mistake?**

Thanks for each reply!

Comment: on windows? did you install gcc?

Comment: on Windows you should use Visual Studio or MinGW. There are windows binaries of gcc but I've need heard of anyone doing cocos2d-x development using them.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yes its on Windows 8. I also installed gcc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found out how to fix that problem.

I just deleted the latest NDK (r10) because it contains only the "arm-linux-androideabi-4.9" in the 
toolchain folder and for some reasons cocos2d-x-3.2 wants the "arm-linux-androideabi-4.8" folder.

Therefore the **SOLUTION** is to download the previous version of NDK (r9) which includes that folder. You can download that version through that link:

http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9-windows-x86_64.zip

I hope I can help other frustrated users.